ByVal target range returned is in unexpected format
The target.address variable that is passed, is $127:$127. In terms of range, what does it mean?
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Excel.Range)
    If r Is Nothing Then Set r = New Revenues
    'ByVal target.address is $127:$127
    r.updateSheet target
End Sub

Later, in r.updateSheet, I attempt to use Application.Intersect(ws.Range("A:A"), Range(target.Address)) and this strange range seems is what makes it fail.

Range("$127:$127") means entire row no. 127. In the case of intersection it is important that both ranges refer to the same sheet. Is ws the same sheet as Target.Parent?

Odd, event though intellisense seems to offer target.Parent, it creates an error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Try to use Application.Intersect(ws.Range("A:A"), ws.Range(target.Address)) if you need your range to be in ws sheet.
